# webscraping in python doesn't return the element I want

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to accomplish web scraping but I can't find the element which I need to use in the code until now when I run it it returns "NONE" (I want to take the header, the time and the line afer the header):

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://maya.tase.co.il/reports/company?q=%7B%22DateFrom%22:%222019-09-26T21:00:00.000Z%22,%22DateTo%22:%222020-03-26T22:00:00.000Z%22,%22events%22:%5B%5D,%22subevents%22:%5B%5D,%22Page%22:1,%22entity%22:1704%7D' , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
week = soup.find(_class='feedItemMessage')
print(week)
```

Comment: Photo which shows what i want to scrape(i show only one exmaple but i want it for each one):
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7m7Q.png

Comment: When enter into this link say denied your access.

Answer (score 0):

The elements, that you are looking for, are generated by JavaScript which is executed after the markup is loaded. `request.get` only fetches the source code of the page and BeautifulSoup only allows you to inspect said source code. Neither executes any JavaScript present.

The data you are looking for is requested separately from, I believe, the following URL https://mayaapi.tase.co.il/api/report/filter through a POST request.

Comment: In other words, the OP either needs a headless browser, or to interact with the underlying page's data api directly.